# How to copy pages/sections from one Pages document to another?

Tags: pages

I have read [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2551974?tstart=0) that you can simply copy/paste pages between documents. When I highlight a page, there is no option to copy and nothing happens (except the typical warning sound) when I hit cmd-c. Drag and drop doesn't work either.
I have the newest OSX and pages versions.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think this used to be an option in the old version of pages - where you could just highlight a page copy it and past it over to a new doc.

Now you would need to select all content on a page copy that and past it over to a new already existing page on a new document.

To select content: if you open the pages window up (larger than the white page) you can drag a selection box over the content you want, starting from off the page.